# Multiple one to many relationship for one table

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm new to Database Design. I have read this question

[Multiple one-to-many relationship for one table](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_windows8-mso_2013_release/multiple-one-to-many-relationship-for-one-table/288475b8-3d8a-4f36-b9d3-56d44c358412)

I have the same question, and In my case, I have one table "Risk" which have 3 attributes with one-to-many relationships, One risk can have multiple "Activity" & " Channel" & "Transaction Method" so i created this design

[image]

I haven't seen a database design like this through my research. My question is this design allowed or any suggestion for my case?

Thank you.

Comment: Your schema can be what ever you want, but what you really need to know is if the schema will suit your business needs. As Bill Karwin has pointed out, your diagram needs updating. Please post an explanation of the relationships in business terms. Do `Activity`, `Channel` and `Transaction Method` represent enumerations, or lookup entries? It is normal to have this many links, but text books wont have them because it complicates the discussion topics. But you need to justify them, here you have not provided any justification, so you leave us to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, but you have a few details to fix:

- I think `Detail Channel` should reference `Channel_ID`, not `Activity_ID`, right? This looks like a copy & paste mistake.
- Likewise, the detail table for `Transaction Method` should reference `TransactionMethod_ID`, not `Activity_ID`.
- And the table name for the detail table for `Transaction Method` needs a different name. Each table in a database must have a unique name, and you already have a table with that name.
- `Channel` and `Transaction Method` need an `ID` column if you reference them by their respective `ID`.

Comment: Yes sir i made a mistakes when uploading the design picture,all your corrections are in accordance with my design picture,Thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: One thing you will learn as a software developer is that there is great importance in being detail-oriented. You need to develop the habit of double-checking your work. It's hard to see typos and copy-paste errors in your own writing, and even harder in code. If you can master the skill of noticing errors, you have a good start!